# Zeros of elementary symmetric polynomials over finite fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

Consider elementary symmetric polynomials in $n$ indeterminates $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ considered over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q$ is sufficiently large. Suppose $s_1(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = x_1 + \ldots + x_n = 1$ and $s_n(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = x_1 \cdots x_n \neq 0$ for some $n$-tuple $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{F}_q^n$.  Does it follows that all the remaining symmetric polynomials are nonzero? If not, what additional constraints imply the same?

Comment: For $q=2$ this is just asking whether if $n$ is odd then $\binom{n}{k}$ is odd for all $k$.  Consider $\binom{5}{2}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what $q$ sufficiently large means in this setting.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger  By Weil's result "Number of solutions to equations over finite fields", the first equation has solutions of order $q^{n-1}$ when $q$ is sufficiently large. Furthermore these solutions $x_i$ can be taken to be nonzero too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\ge3,q>5$ be not too small. Pick $x_3,\ldots,x_n$ arbitrarily non-zero. Let $a=x_3+\ldots+x_n$, $b=x_3x_4+\ldots$ be their first few elementary symmetric  polynomials. By changing one value at most, we can ensure $a\ne0$. I want to pick $x_1\ne0,x_2\ne0$ such that $x_1+x_2+a\ne0$ and
$x_1x_2+(x_1+x_2)a+b=0$. We also want to avoid $x_2=-a$ and $x_2=b/a$. Then we must take $x_1=\frac{-b-x_2a}{x_2+a} $ (is defined and non-Zero!). The condition $x_1+x_2+a\ne0$ turns into $a^2-b+x_2a+x_2^2\ne0$. Thus at most two more choices for $x_2$ are forbidden. All in all, only five choices for $x_2$ are forbidden, so at least one still remains and gives us an $n$-tuple of values in $\Bbb F_q$ with non-zero sum (or after scaling: sum equals $1$), non-zero product, but the second degree elementary symmetric polynomial is zero.

Comment: @Hagen-von-Etizen Is it possible to choose $x_i \in \mathbb{F}_q$ such that all the symmetric polynomials are nonzero?

Comment: @Vanya Certainly if you start with a polynomial with all coefficients nonzero and increase $q$ until the polynomial splits into linear factors

Comment: @Hagen-von-Etizen Thank you very much for the reply. Your solution was simply brilliant. ​ Do you think it is possible to find a tuple ​$(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ such that each $x_i$ is a $k$th power for a fixed $k$ relatively prime to $q$ ​such that the first and the last symmetric polynomial ​in $y_1^k, \ldots, y_n^k$ ​evaluate to nonzero but the remaining ones evaluate to zero. ​ The existence of $y_i$ such that the sum $y_1^k + \ldots + y_n^k = 1$ and the product $y_1^k \ldots y_n^k \neq 0$ follows from Weil's theorem on number of solutions to equations over finite fields.

Comment: @Hagen-von-Etizen Your solution above is interesting. How big $q$ should be does not depend on $n$.